# setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints

Tags: uibutton, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to create a custom keyboard for iOS 10 and in my code I have

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
...
```

but I get the error

> Value of type 'UIButton' has no member 'setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints'

Scouring online forums I can't find any explanation of what happened to this method between `Swift 2` and `Swift 3`.

I can't find any mention of it in the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton#overview)

Was it deprecated? Was it renamed?

I'm using `Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)`

Comment: I believe you just use the property... translates... = false.

Comment: wow so `swift 1` = property, `swift 2` = method, then `swift 3` = property again? that's so weird.. but it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as user Fogmeister pointed out is that in `swift 3` `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is now a property **again** and not a method as it was in `swift 2`.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```